# Creating weather forecast based on ip geolocation using google cloud function and Aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, serverless

my task is to to create endpoint, where user gets weather forecast based on his ip geolocation.

For getting geolocation I'm using google cloud function:

```
const cors = require('cors')

function _geolocation(req, res) {
  const data = {
    country: req.headers["x-appengine-country"],
    region: req.headers["x-appengine-region"],
    city: req.headers["x-appengine-city"],
    cityLatLong: req.headers["x-appengine-citylatlong"],
    userIP: req.headers["x-appengine-user-ip"],
  }

  res.json(data)
};

exports.geolocation = (req, res) => {
  const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true })

  return corsHandler(req, res, function() {
    return _geolocation(req, res);
  });
};
```

Lamda gets ip from google function and then sends weather forecast for that location.
creating Lambda with serverless framework:

```
module.exports.weather = async (event) => {
  const weather = await fetchWeather()
  console.log(event)
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Function executed successfully!",
        weather: weather,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
};
```

Curently my  problem is that I'm getting location of aws server and not the users, what can be done to connect google cloud and aws lmabda in a way to get users location?

Comment: How are you connecting AWS Lambda to Google Cloud Functions?

Comment: I'm using axios for connection: axios.get(link to google function)